# Convergence in $L^2$ of the stochastic integral $\int\limits^{t}_{0}\frac{B_s}{e}1_{B_s\in(-e,e)}dB_s$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

> Let $e\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $B_t$ 1-dimensional Brownian motion. Consider $$X_t=\int^{t}_{0}\frac{B_s}{e}1_{B_s\in(-e,e)}dB_s.$$
>   How to show that $X_t \to 0$ in $L^2$ as $e\to0$?

Obviously the result should follow from Ito isometry. However I am stuck on evaluating the expectation $E[X_t^2]$ due to the indicator function.

Comment: You might be aware of the identity $$E\left(\int_0^tX_sdB_s\int_0^tY_sdB_s\right)=\int_0^tE(X_sY_s)ds.$$ Can you use it to approach your question?

Comment: @Did thanks. Do you think this makes sense:

$E\Bigg[\Bigg(\int^{t}_{0}\frac{B_s}{e}dB_s\Bigg)^2\Bigg(\int^{t}_{0}1_{B_s\in(-e,e)}dB_s\Bigg)^2\Bigg] = E\Bigg[\int^{t}_{0}\frac{B_s^2}{e^2}ds\int^{t}_{0}1_{B_s\in(-e,e)}ds\Bigg]$

$=E\Bigg[\int^{t}_{0}\frac{B_s^2}{e^2}|s\in[0,t]: B_s\in (-e,e)|d_s\Bigg]$


where $|F|$ denotes Lebesgue measure of the set $F$. Then when $e\to0$ this measure goes to 0 and thus the whole equation has a limit 0?

Comment: Are you taking the expectation of the square of a stochastic integral times the square of another stochastic integral? I fail to see why and i think my first comment explains how to proceed.

Comment: Okay, but using your argument I can prove just convergence in mean, i. e.  the original integral converges to 0 in $L^1$. I cannot see how to proceed when proving the convergence in $L^2$ when I have a square of stochastic integral in the expectation.

Comment: No, what you call my argument proves the convergence in $L^2$ (from which the convergence in $L^1$ follows since we are dealing with *probability* measures), not the convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: @Did thanks, I think I finally saw something:

$E\Bigg[\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{e}1_{B_s\in (-e,e)}dB_s\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{e}1_{B_s\in (-e,e)}dB_s\Bigg]=\int_0^tE\Big[ \frac{B_s^2}{e^2}1_{B_s\in (-e,e)}\Big]ds $ is there a way now to deal with indicator function?

Comment: Second hint: Let $Z$ denote some standard normal random variable, then, for every $t$, $B_t$ is distributed like $\sqrt{t}Z$. Can you use this to rewrite the last integral in your comment in terms of $Z$ alone?

Comment: $\int_0^t E\Big[  \frac{s Z^2}{e^2}1_{Z\in(-\frac{e}{\sqrt{s}},\frac{e}{\sqrt{s}})}\Big]  ds $

Comment: Indeed. And now, of course you change the order of integration and you are left with estimating $$Z^2\int_0^ts\,\mathbf 1_{|Z|<\epsilon/\sqrt{s}}\,ds.$$ Come! Just do it...