# Regarding a proof of Tanaka's formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

This is in context of a proof of Tanaka's formula. I know that the general idea of the proof is to approximate |x| by $C^2$ functions. Therefore, we defined $f_\epsilon(x) = \sqrt{\epsilon + x^2}$ and got by Ito's formula
\begin{equation}
f_\epsilon (B_t) = \sqrt{\epsilon} + \int_0^t \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{\epsilon + B_s^2}} \ dB_s + \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}\  \frac{\epsilon}{(\epsilon + B_s^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ ds.
\end{equation}
Now it was proposed to show that for any $T>0$
\begin{equation}
\sup_{t\leq T} \left| \int_0^t \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{\epsilon + B_s^2}} \ dB_s - \int_0^t sgn(B_s) \ dB_s \right| \to 0 \text{   in } L^2 \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0
\end{equation}
which is not difficult to see using Ito's Isometry and Doob's inequalities. Now it is said that we can infer that there exists a continuous and increasing process $L$ s.t.
\begin{equation}
|B_t| = \int_0^t sgn(B_s)\ dB_s + L_t 
\end{equation}for all $t\geq 0$ and for any $T>0$
\begin{equation}
\sup_{t\leq T} \left| \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}\  \frac{\epsilon}{(\epsilon + B_s^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ ds - L_t \right| \to 0 \text{   in } L^2 \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0.
\end{equation}
This is the part I don't get. How can we conclude that there exists such a process $L$? What does the $L^2$ convergence give us here and what do we need the supremum for?

Also, $sgn(0)= 0$ otherwise the usual definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fixed $\epsilon>0$ set

$$L_t^{(\epsilon)} := \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \frac{\epsilon}{(\epsilon+B_s^2)^{3/2}} \, ds,$$

i.e.

$$f_{\epsilon}(B_t) = \sqrt{\epsilon} + \int_0^t \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{\epsilon+B_s^2}} \, dB_s+  L_{t}^{\epsilon}.$$

Since $f_{\epsilon}(B_t) \to |B_t|$ in $L^2$ and the stochastic integral converges in $L^2$ to $\int_0^t \text{sgn}(B_s) \, dB_s$, it follows that

$$L_t^{(\epsilon)} = f_{\epsilon}(B_t)-\sqrt{\epsilon} - \int_0^t \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{\epsilon+B_s^2}} \, dB_s \xrightarrow[L^2]{\epsilon \to 0} |B_t| - \int_0^t \text{sgn}(B_s) \, dB_s =: L_t $$

for fixed $t \geq 0$. Note that $(L_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has (a modification with) continuous sample paths since the stochastic integral has continuous sample paths a.s. (the continuity of $|B_t|$ is obvious from the continuity of $B_t$). Now

$$\sup_{t \leq T} |L_t^{(\epsilon)}-L_t| \leq \sqrt{\epsilon}+ \sup_{t \leq T} |f_{\epsilon}(B_t)-|B_t|| + \sup_{t \leq T} \left| \int_0^t \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{\epsilon+B_s^2}} \, dB_s - \int_0^t \text{sgn}(B_s) \, dB_s \right|.$$

The right-hand side converges to $0$ in $L^2$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, and so does the right-hand side. Convergence in $L^2$ implies that there exists a subsequence converging almost surely, i.e. we can find $\epsilon_k \downarrow 0$ such that $$\sup_{t \leq T} |L_t^{(\epsilon_k)}-L_t| \to 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$ Since $t \mapsto L_t^{(\epsilon)}$ is increasing, it follows that the limit is also increasing in $t$:

$$L_s = \lim_{k \to \infty} L_s^{(\epsilon_k)} \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} L_t^{(\epsilon_k)} = L_t$$

for any $s \leq t \leq T$.

**Remark:** Note that we have shown, as a by-product, that

$$|B_t| = \int_0^t \text{sgn}(B_s) \, dB_s + L_t$$

is the Doob-Meyer decomposition of the submartingale $(|B_t|)_{t \geq 0}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! One last question: Could you tell me why the supremum was at all necessary then?

Comment: @Flo Typically one uses the uniform continuity on compact sets to infer sample paths properties of the limit. In the last part of my answer, I showed that for every $T>0$ there exists a null set $N=N(T)$ such that $L_s(\omega) \leq L_t(\omega)$ for all $s \leq t \leq T$ and $\omega \in \Omega \setminus N_T$. Mind that the exceptional null set does not depend on $s$ and $t$. As a consequence (choosing $T=N \uparrow \infty$), we get a null set $N$ such that $L_s(\omega) \leq L_t(\omega)$ for all $s \leq t$ and $\omega \in \Omega \backslash N$. We can only deduce the existence of this [...]

Comment: "uniform" null set because we have uniform convergence on compact sets. If we only knew that $L_t^{(\epsilon)} \to L_t$ in $L^2$ for each fixed $t$, we could still find sequences $\epsilon_k \downarrow 0$ such that $L_t = \lim_k L_{t}^{\epsilon_k}$ and $L_s = \lim_k L_s^{(\epsilon_k)}$ for some **fixed** $s \leq t$, and deduce that $L_s \leq L_t$ almost surely. However, now the exceptional null set depends on $s$ and $t$ (... which is bad).

Comment: Another typical application of the uniform convergence is deduce that the limit has continuous sample paths (...which is not really necessary in our case here, because we already know it).

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!

Comment: @saz Sorry to bug you, but I'm having trouble seeing why $$ \int^{t}_{0} \frac{B_{s}}{\sqrt{\epsilon + B_{s}^{2}}}dB_{s} \to \int^{t}_{0} sgn(B_{s})dB_{s}$$ in $L^{2}$. Specifically thinking of the stochastic integral as a random variable $X_{\epsilon}$ how to we compute $E[X^{2}_{\epsilon}]?$

Comment: I think I see now, I think we need to use linearity of expectation. There is an identity which was used in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423388/convergence-in-l2-of-the-stochastic-integral-int-limitst-0-fracb-se